# XMLTextReader missing first element

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I'm writing a configuration storage method for one of my clients and they requested that it be in XML. I've managed to get it to work other than one issue; the first element is missing. My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
    <username>test</username> 
    <password>pass</password>
    <autologin>true</autologin>
</config>
```

My Parsing command is:

```
    void parseConfigFile()
    {
        while (configstr.Read())
        {
            if (configstr.IsStartElement())
            {
                config.Add(configstr.Name,configstr.ReadString());
            }
        }
    }
```

and the result (configstr) is:

```
autologin = true
config = 
password = pass
```

Comment: Any reason you're using this low-level way of XML processing and not a more convenient way like [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195.aspx)?

Comment: Just what the client requested.

Comment: Although, now that I look at that LINQ-to-XML link you gave, can you give any tutorial on usage?

Comment: The client is telling you how to code something? Yikes.

Comment: First result from google: [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: The client is also a developer, but not of C# but instead PHP. They're considering making things cross-platform. The XML I provided is just for one app.

Comment: .NET comes with multiple ways of XML processing. Each way allows you to consume and produce any XML file, but some are more convenient than others. You have selected the least convenient way. Have a look at LINQ-to-XML.

Comment: I've tried LINQ-to-XML. Only problem I'm having now is it's complaining about non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Nevermind, my bad. I did new XDocument instead of XDocument.Load. @dtb can you post the LINQ-to-XML suggestion as an answer so I can accept it, please?

Comment: FYI, even if required to use the low-level method, you should use `XmlReader.Create` instead of `new XmlTextReader()`, which has been deprecated since .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var document = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var config = document.Root;

var userName = (string)config.Element("username");
var password = (string)config.Element("password");
var autologin = (bool)config.Element("autologin");
```